# Data aggregation in NodeJS with promisified functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise

I'd like to aggregate data from MongoDB in NodeJS with promisified functions. 
My script with dump are here https://github.com/network-spy/lego

Little description: there are 2 collections in database: "zip" and "restaurants". "zip" contains zip codes of locations and "restaurants" contains information about restaurants with zip codes. So script should create new collection "stat" and fill it with documents like: 
{"zip_code" : "01002", "restaurants" : [ list of restaurants ] }

The problem is that in "zip" collection there are 29353 documents, but after script processing I get "stat" collection with 29026 documents(sometimes count of documents can change).

I guess it's because of broken synchronization somewhere in my JS code. Could you look please at my code and advice anything how to repair it?

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongoDbUrl = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/world';

MongoClient.connect(mongoDbUrl, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Connected to server.");
    clearStat(db).then(
        result => {
            console.log(result);
            processZips(db).then(
                result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    closeMongoDBConnection(db);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    closeMongoDBConnection(db);
                }
            );
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
            closeMongoDBConnection(db);
        }
    );
});

let closeMongoDBConnection = (db) => {
    db.close();
    console.log("Disconnected from server.");
};

let clearStat = (db) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.collection('stat').deleteMany({}, function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve('Stat data cleared');
        });
    });
};


let processZips = (db) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.collection('zip').find({}, {"_id":1}).each((err, zipCode) => {
            if (zipCode == null) {
                resolve('Zips precessed');
            } else if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                findRestaurantsByZip(db, zipCode._id).then(
                    result => {
                        insertToStat(db, zipCode._id, result).then(
                            result => {
                                console.log('Inserted: ');
                                console.dir(result);
                            },
                            error => {
                                reject(error);
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    error => {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    });
};

let findRestaurantsByZip = (db, zipCode) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.collection('restaurant').find({"address.zipcode": zipCode}).toArray((err, restaurants) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(restaurants);
        });
    });
};

let insertToStat = (db, zip, restaurants) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let statDocument = {};
        statDocument.zip_code = zip;
        statDocument.restaurants = restaurants;
        db.collection('stat').insertOne(statDocument).then(
            result => {
                resolve(statDocument);
            },
            error => {
                reject(error);
            }
        );
    });
};
```

Comment: I've edited in the code from your git that I believe is the issue - it's only 100 lines. I've seen longer, unformatted code in questions, so you really should add code to the question when you can

Comment: Ok. Thank you for help with it

Comment: Up to date versions of the node.js mongodb driver have native support for promises, therefore no need for explicit promises in your functions. The code should simplify significantly and become easier to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a simplification of your processZips function. This is functionally identical to your code but uses Promise chaining rather than nested Promises

```
let processZips = (db) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    db.collection('zip').find({}, {"_id":1}).each((err, zipCode) => {
        if (zipCode == null) {
            resolve('Zips precessed');
        } else if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            findRestaurantsByZip(db, zipCode._id)
            .then(result => insertToStat(db, zipCode._id, result))
            .then(result => console.log('Inserted: ', result))
            .catch(error => reject(error));
        }
    })
);
```

The problem **may** be (I can't test anything) that you resolve the `processZips` promise at the end of the `.each` processing. This "triggers" the .then that closes the database. However, due to the asynchronous find/insert code it may well be that some of that is "in progress" at the time. I don't profess to know mongodb well, so I don't know what closing the db while processing is still active would do - seems likely that's the reason why you're output data is "short"

So, there's two ways to approach this

1 - process each zipCode in series, i.e. each find/insert waits for the previous to complete, and then resolve when last zipCode is done

```
let processZips = (db) => {
    // set p to a resolved Promise so the first find/insert will kick off
    let p = Promise.resolve();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        db.collection('zip').find({}, {"_id":1}).each((err, zipCode) => {
            if (zipCode == null) {
                // wait for last insert to complete before resolving the Promise
                resolve(p.then(() => resolve('Zips precessed'))); // see note 1, 2
            } else if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                // wait for previous insert to complete before starting new find/insert
                p = p
                .then(() => findRestaurantsByZip(db, zipCode._id))
                .then(result => insertToStat(db, zipCode._id, result))
                .then(result => console.log('Inserted: ', result)); // see note 1
            }
        })
    );
};
```

With this code, as soon as a find/insert rejects, no more find/insert will actually be performed

2 - process each code in "parallel", i.e. kick off all the find/insert and then resolve when **all** zipCode are done

```
let processZips = (db) => {
    // create an array for all the find/insert Promises
    let p = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        db.collection('zip').find({}, {"_id":1}).each((err, zipCode) => {
            if (zipCode == null) {
                // wait for all find/insert to complete before resolving this Promise
                resolve(Promise.all(p).then(() => 'Zips precessed')); // see note 1, 2
            } else if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                p.push(findRestaurantsByZip(db, zipCode._id)
                    .then(result => insertToStat(db, zipCode._id, result))
                    .then(result => console.log('Inserted: ', result))
                ); // see note 1
            }
        })
    );
};
```

The one caveat with the second method is, like in your original code, if one of the find/insert fails that wont stop subsequent find/insert from processing.

You'll notice that there seems to be a lack of error handling compared to your original code. This code uses the 2 "features" of promises.

1. rejections will "flow through" the promise chain,
2. if you resolve a promise with a rejected promise, it is identical to rejecting the promise.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. The second method - is what I wanted to implement.